# Python read-only lists using the property decorator

Tags: python, properties, getter, shallow-copy

### Short Version

Can I make a read-only list using Python's property system?

### Long Version

I have created a Python class that has a list as a member. Internally, I would like it to do something every time the list is modified.  If this were C++, I would create getters and setters that would allow me to do my bookkeeping whenever the setter was called, and I would have the getter return a `const` reference, so that the compiler would yell at me if I tried to do modify the list through the getter. In Python, we have the property system, so that writing vanilla getters and setters for every data member is (thankfully) no longer necessary.

However, consider the following script:

```
def main():

    foo = Foo()
    print('foo.myList:', foo.myList)

    # Here, I'm modifying the list without doing any bookkeeping.
    foo.myList.append(4)
    print('foo.myList:', foo.myList)

    # Here, I'm modifying my "read-only" list.
    foo.readOnlyList.append(8)
    print('foo.readOnlyList:', foo.readOnlyList)


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._myList = [1, 2, 3]
        self._readOnlyList = [5, 6, 7]

    @property
    def myList(self):
        return self._myList

    @myList.setter
    def myList(self, rhs):
        print("Insert bookkeeping here")
        self._myList = rhs

    @property
    def readOnlyList(self):
        return self._readOnlyList


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
foo.myList: [1, 2, 3]
# Note there's no "Insert bookkeeping here" message.
foo.myList: [1, 2, 3, 4]
foo.readOnlyList: [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

This illustrates that the absence of the concept of `const` in Python allows me to modify my list using the `append()` method, despite the fact that I've made it a property.  This can bypass my bookkeeping mechanism (`_myList`), or it can be used to modify lists that one might like to be read-only (`_readOnlyList`).

One workaround would be to return a deep copy of the list in the getter method (i.e. `return self._myList[:]`).  This could mean a lot of extra copying, if the list is large or if the copy is done in an inner loop.  (But premature optimization is the root of all evil, anyway.)  In addition, while a deep copy would prevent the bookkeeping mechanism from being bypassed, if someone were to call `.myList.append()` , their changes would be silently discarded, which could generate some painful debugging.  It would be nice if an exception were raised, so that they'd know they were working against the class' design.

A fix for this last problem would be not to use the property system, and make "normal" getter and setter methods:

```
def myList(self):
    # No property decorator.
    return self._myList[:]

def setMyList(self, myList):
    print('Insert bookkeeping here')
    self._myList = myList
```

If the user tried to call `append()`, it would look like `foo.myList().append(8)`, and those extra parentheses would clue them in that they might be getting a copy, rather than a reference to the internal list's data.  The negative thing about this is that it is kind of un-Pythonic to write getters and setters like this, and if the class has other list members, I would have to either write getters and setters for those (eww), or make the interface inconsistent.  (I think a slightly inconsistent interface might be the least of all evils.)

Is there another solution I am missing?  Can one make a read-only list using Python's property system?

Comment: The best workaround may be to let go of the idea that you can make things read-only.  We're All Consenting Adults in python, after all :-)

Comment: Why not using frozenset ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422409/difference-between-tuples-and-frozensets-in-python

Comment: or return a `tuple()` from your property; that's a read-only sequence.

Comment: @roippi That is a good point.  Python's lack of `const` is a deliberate design decision with drawbacks and benefits, with the latter presumably outweighing the former.  However, the property decorator seems to be explicitly designed to make an attribute read-only.  The shallow copy/append issue seemed to undermine it, and it seemed like a general problem (if you can call it that), so I was wondering what The Smart Way was of dealing with it.  My takeaway is that properties are really designed with primatives in mind, but  subclassing (or using a tuple) is one way to work with the situation.

Comment: @ngb: i added an answer below with the suggestion to inherit from property instead. am really curious what you think of this solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could have method return a wrapper around your original list -- `collections.Sequence` might be of help for writing it.  Or, you could return a `tuple` -- The overhead of copying a list into a tuple is *often* negligible.

Ultimately though, if a user wants to change the underlying list, they can and there's really nothing you can do to stop them.  (After all, they have direct access to `self._myList` if they want it).

I think that the pythonic way to do something like this is to document that they *shouldn't* change the list and that if the *do*, then it's their fault when their program crashes and burns.

Comment: Or return a tuple from the getter, perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Yeah, I thought about that shortly after I posted ... The only downside with `tuple` is that it makes a copy.  Most of the time, that shouldn't matter though...

Comment: Only a copy of the indices; and if the list is <= 20 items, chances are Python can re-use one of the cached tuple objects it keeps around.

Comment: @mgilson Thanks!  I accepted this answer since it was one of the earliest answers, and it mentioned both subclassing and returning a tuple.  Regarding really trying to stop the user-- it's not so much that I want to stop the user; I just want to help them by giving them some kind of warning if they're doing something that might have side effects they don't anticipate.  If they futz with a variable starting with "_", I think it's fair to suppose they're already aware they're assuming a higher level of risk and leave it at that.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I like the idea of casting to a tuple.  Also, I did not know that Python had some optimizations like that regarding converting lists to tuples.  That addresses my concern about extra copying, somewhat.  Off the top of your head, do you know of any place that describes this optimization?  I googled around a little for it, but evidently my google-fu is weak.

Comment: I covered the behaviour in [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135542/how-is-tuple-implemented-in-cpython).

Answer (score 3):

> despite the fact that I've made it a property

It does not matter if it's a property, you are returning a pointer to the list so you can modify it.

I'd suggest creating a [list subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432719/python-how-can-i-inherit-from-the-built-in-list-type) and overriding `append` and `__add__` methods

Comment: Thanks.  Subclassing is probably the most general solution to this kind of thing, I think.

Comment: Old question and old answer, but I feel like I should point out that this solution would break [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), so should be used with care. If I remember correctly, Kotlin does that with List and MutableList.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solutions of returning a tuple or subclassing list for the return, seem like nice solutions, but i was wondering whether it wouldn't be easier to subclass the decorator instead? Not sure it this might be a stupid idea:

- using this `safe_property` protects against accidental sending mixed API signals (internal immutable attributes are "protected" against all operations, while the for mutable attributes, some operations are still allowed with the normal `property` builtin)
- advantage: easier to use than to implement custom return types everywhere -> easier to internalize
- disadvantage: necessity to use different name

```
class FrozenList(list):

    def _immutable(self, *args, **kws):
        raise TypeError('cannot change object - object is immutable')

    pop = _immutable
    remove = _immutable
    append = _immutable
    clear = _immutable
    extend = _immutable
    insert = _immutable
    reverse = _immutable


class FrozenDict(dict):

    def _immutable(self, *args, **kws):
        raise TypeError('cannot change object - object is immutable')

    __setitem__ = _immutable
    __delitem__ = _immutable
    pop = _immutable
    popitem = _immutable
    clear = _immutable
    update = _immutable
    setdefault = _immutable


class safe_property(property):

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        candidate = super().__get__(obj, objtype)
        if isinstance(candidate, dict):
            return FrozenDict(candidate)
        elif isinstance(candidate, list):
            return FrozenList(candidate)
        elif isinstance(candidate, set):
            return frozenset(candidate)
        else:
            return candidate


class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self._internal_lst = [1]

    @property
    def internal_lst(self):
        return self._internal_lst

    @safe_property
    def internal_lst_safe(self):
        return self._internal_lst


if __name__ == '__main__':

    foo = Foo()

    foo.internal_lst.append(2)
    # foo._internal_lst is now [1, 2]
    foo.internal_lst_safe.append(3)
    # this throws an exception
```

Very much interested in other opinions on this as i haven't seen this implemented somewhere else.

Comment: Might be a solution, if it is actually possible to catch all functions that mute a list. Do you know if this can be guaranteed without hours of researching? In any case, this is quite a code-intensive solution. Where possible I think that I would prefer to use a tuple instead. A named tuple might work as a replacement for a dict. Also not sure if returning an object of type FrozenList might break some typed interfaces?

Comment: Good point about all mutability options. Haven't found a source on whether this covers everything. It is indeed a code-intensive solution, but one which might be worth the overhead when implemented in a library/framework: the code is only once, the application of the improved decorator might be frequent. Frozenlist is indeed a different type, but less so than a tuple. isinstance(result, list) still works for FrozenList, but not for tuple.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by using the `Sequence` type hint, which unlike  `list` is non-modifiable:

```
from typing import Sequence

def foo() -> Sequence[int]:
    return []

result = foo()
result.append(10)
result[0] = 10
```

Both `mypy` and `pyright` will give an error when trying to modify a list that is hinted with `Sequence`:

```
$ pyright /tmp/foo.py
  /tmp/foo.py:7:8 - error: Cannot access member "append" for type "Sequence[int]"
    Member "append" is unknown (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
  /tmp/foo.py:8:1 - error: "__setitem__" method not defined on type "Sequence[int]" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
2 errors, 0 warnings, 0 informations
```

Python itself however ignores those hints, so a little must be taken to make sure that either of those type checkers are run regularly or part of the build process.

There is also a `Final` type hint, that acts similar to C++ `const`, it however only provides protection of the variable in which the list reference is stored, not for the list itself, so it's not useful here, but might be of use in other situations.

Answer (score 0):

Why is a list preferable to a tuple? Tuples are, for most intents and purposes, 'immutable lists' - so by nature they will act as read-only objects that can't be directly set or modified. At that point one simply needs to not write said setter for that property.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self, list_data, tuple_data):
...             self._list = list(list_data)
...             self._tuple = tuple(tuple_data)
...     @property
...     def list(self):
...             return self._list
...     @list.setter
...     def list(self, new_v):
...             self._list.append(new_v)
...     @property
...     def tuple(self):
...             return self._tuple
... 
>>> Stick = A((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))
>>> Stick.list
[1, 2, 3]
>>> Stick.tuple
(4, 5, 6)
>>> Stick.list = 4 ##this feels like a weird way to 'cover-up' list.append, but w/e
>>> Stick.list = "Hey"
>>> Stick.list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'Hey']
>>> Stick.tuple = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>>
```

Comment: In principle, I like having the member as a list so that I can use the += operator (which calls the setter), rather than having to write and use some kind of `addToMyMember()` method.  But your point is well-taken; if I'd really like something to be immutable, just make it immutable.  I may just end up doing that, += operator be damned.

Answer (score 0):

The two main suggestions seem to be either using a tuple as a read-only list, or subclassing list. I like both of those approaches.

Returning a tuple from the getter, or using a tuple in the first place, prevents one from using the `+=` operator, which can be a useful operator and also triggers the bookkeeping mechanism by calling the setter. However, returning a tuple is a one-line change, which is nice if you would like to program defensively but judge that adding a whole other class to your script might be unnecessarily complicated.

Here is a script that illustrates both approaches:

```
import collections


def main():

    foo = Foo()
    print('foo.myList:', foo.myList)

    try:
        foo.myList.append(4)
    except RuntimeError:
        print('Appending prevented.')

    # Note that this triggers the bookkeeping, as we would like.
    foo.myList += [3.14]
    print('foo.myList:', foo.myList)

    try:
        foo.readOnlySequence.append(8)
    except AttributeError:
        print('Appending prevented.')
    print('foo.readOnlySequence:', foo.readOnlySequence)


class UnappendableList(collections.UserList):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = kwargs.pop('data')
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.data = data

    def append(self, item):
        raise RuntimeError('No appending allowed.')


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._myList = [1, 2, 3]
        self._readOnlySequence = [5, 6, 7]

    @property
    def myList(self):
        return UnappendableList(data=self._myList)

    @myList.setter
    def myList(self, rhs):
        print('Insert bookkeeping here')
        self._myList = rhs

    @property
    def readOnlySequence(self):
        # or just use a tuple in the first place
        return tuple(self._readOnlySequence)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
foo.myList: [1, 2, 3]
Appending prevented.
Insert bookkeeping here
foo.myList: [1, 2, 3, 3.14]
Appending prevented.
foo.readOnlySequence: (5, 6, 7)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23474648/2) to the question [Python read-only lists using the property decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474648/python-read-only-lists-using-the-property-decorator) by the OP [ngb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3604334/ngb) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>